# How to run a mysql loop from a posted array and extract results to a CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

I have searched for hours to try and find a simple answer to this query I am having. I'm very sure it is covered in many ways, by other answers at least partially. I need a clear answer specific to what I am doing because I'm having difficulty trying to put together an answer that works for me from a bunch of other differently formatted and structured questions/answers.

I have a form which is posting a range of results intended to be used as keys for a mysql lookup loop. This is working fine - my post results in a successful array. For example:

```
$payarr = $_POST['pay'];
print_r($payarr);
```

Results in:

```
Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 7 [2] => 1 )
```

Which is good given that the I want to run a mysqli process select the rows where claim_id is each of the values in $payarr. I then want to use fputcsv to write each of these rows fully, into a CSV file that is uniquely named by the days date and time that this is all run.

I have fragments of code that don't work and my frustration at trying to cobble something together that does work is getting a bit nuts. Can someone please show me how to do this effectively?

At the moment my code looks like this (but fails miserably):

```
<?php
include ("../conf/dbconfig.php");
include ("../conf/funcs.php");
include ("../conf/privs.php");

if($privs == 500) {
    $view = $_POST['view'];
    $payarr = $_POST['pay'];
    $ts = date('Ymd-His');

print_r($payarr); //Testing to make sure our array to select from has arrived here ok.

    //ob_start();
    $fp = fopen('../csv/ResultsFile_'.$ts.'.csv', 'w');

    foreach($payarr as $val) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "'SELECT * FROM claims' WHERE claim_id='$val'");
        //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $payarr;
            echo $val;
            //fputcsv($fp, $row);
            print_r($row);
        }
    }    
    fclose($fp);
//  return ob_get_clean();


} else {
    header("Location: http://www.google.com.au/");
    die;
}
?>
```

I'm willing (and happy) to rewrite the entire thing just as long as it works, so any help and suggestions are very appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

BTW - The $view value is not important in this process but is here as it will be passed back to the resulting header once this all works.

Comment: You need to give information on what exactly is not working rather than vaguely state you have fragments of code that don't work.  What doesn't work?  Also, think about making a single query for your data in the form `WHERE claim_id IN(X, Y, Z)` (where X, Y, Z are grabbed from your array). Also, you probably shouldn't bother opening a file for writing until you know you have a good database result set of one of more rows. You also have done nothing to prevent against SQL injection. Finally, remove single quotes around `SELECT * FROM claims`

Comment: @MikeBrant - Thanks, that is exactly the sort of vague and fragmented answer that has been doing my head in. Not helpful at all. I've clearly stated what I am trying to achieve and I have given precisely the code that I am trying with that is not working. Why do I need to spell out the errors and failures I get from it, when to someone with better knowledge than me should be able to see it directly? I am looking for help, not criticism or the need to spell out the obvious. Sorry if it sounds personal but your response is very unhelpful to me.

Comment: @crafter - Good point, noted. Have now changes this but it doesn't address or help with the main problem. Thanks though. Code updated to reflect change.

Comment: Wow. Great comment above. On someone who should see for the errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few rough suggestions (you may need to adapt):

1) Change your query to use `IN` for the possible values, so you only have to execute one DB query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM claims WHERE claim_id IN (" . implode(",",$payarr) . ")");
```

2) Make sure you are actually getting a DB result, instead of just assuming:

```
if(!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    die("We didn't get any results from the DB!"); // Obviously you'll want better error handling
}
```

3) Now you can open your file, knowing that you need it. Make sure to verify it worked, since you could easily hit a permissions issue:

```
$fp = fopen('../csv/ResultsFile_'.$ts.'.csv', 'w');
if(!$fp) { 
    die("We couldn't open the CSV file for writing, check permissions!"); // Obviously you'll want better error handling
}
```

4) Now loop through your DB results and store them:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```

5) Does your CSV file need a header row? If so change `mysqli_fetch_array()` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and stick this inside your loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(!isset($header)) {
        $header = array_keys($row);
        fputcsv($fp, $header);
    }

    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```

6) Only now should you close your file (in your code you do it inside the `foreach` loop):

```
fclose($fp);
```

7) Sanitize your `$payarr`. It could be as simple as:

```
$payarr = is_array($_POST['pay']) ? array_map('intval', $_POST['pay']) : array();
```

You may want to do more than that. But at least you're guaranteed to have an array with only integer values (and as long as you have no `claim_id` values of 0, it's harmless to have zeros in the array).

Hope that helps, at least track down where your code is failing.

Comment: Huge THANK YOU! After adpating your helpful pointers this now works perfectly, with one small exception. The resulting CSV has all the details entered in duplicate per row! IE in the database an entry might consist of:
claim_id forename surname date ...
In the CSV, if it is a selected claim, is it being entered in as:
claim_id claim_id forename forename surname surname date date ...

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Inside the while loop `print_r($row)` to see what the exact array is that you're writing to csv

Comment: This is a little odd but... I changed the code to give me a CSV **with** header cells to see what it would look like. Instead I did not get header cells at all, I got the resulting CSV without duplication - exactly as I wanted initially. So although I don't understand why, it seems the issue is resolved now. I'm curious to know why though... However once again, huge thanks. Am marking the question as answered. Still going to play with it though..!! :)

Comment: Update: Have used print_r($row) on both the with-header and non-header versions. The non-header replicates each column value mysteriously, while the with-header version does not. Would you care to view the full code I am now using? I expect the reason why will become clear to you right off. It's lost on me. :/

Comment: @Cassandra Sure I could take a look at your full code. Might be easiest to stick it over on http://pastebin.com/ at this point

Comment: @Cassandra Actually I found an issue with the header code I gave you. I updated my answer. Also I create a simulation (with a manual array instead of a DB result) that loops through and writes CSV output. See here: http://3v4l.org/ZumpB

Comment: I'd move this to chat but don't have a high enough reputation. Have posted the code I am using now at http://pastebin.com/6X20Wywn

Comment: @Cassandra Did you look at my recent comments? Or my updated code? I fixed the header issue, your code doesn't reflect that. Also you're still running that select query multiple times inside a foreach loop! Get rid of the foreach loop entirely, you don't need it, that was the whole point of the `WHERE IN` query.

Comment: And what's the result?

Comment: Result is exactly what is expected - with headers. I have now one or two additional questions but they are not related directly to this so I won't continue on here though. They're related to downloading the resulting CSV file. Once again huge thanks, your help and patience with me is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: I have another query if you're keen to take a look. Your help on the above was really brilliant and made sense to me. Any chance you'd look at this one for me also?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603129/how-to-generate-an-editable-table-in-html-from-cross-referencing-two-mysql-db-ta

Comment: @Cassandra You're asking way too much in that new question. Need to break your problem into bite sized chunks. Focus on the query first, post a question and work through getting the SQL results that you need. Then later perhaps a question about the HTML/radiobutton interaction. You'll get a lot more help on this site that way.

Comment: I'm not sure how to break it up. The end result is what is required, if I break it up I'd be omitting the end requirements and this seem to frustrate people that I was not clear at the beginning.

Comment: By the way - I don't need help with the html part of the situation. I know html and css well, I was simply outlining the detail about the radio buttons so that the relationship was clear.